# block incoming request providing a fake ssh certificate, would that be enough?

Tags: linux, ssh, fail2ban

I'd like to automatically block the IPs of requests that are providing a fake ssh certificate or key

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection from XX.XXX.XXX.XX port XXXXX: Connection corrupted [preauth]
```

Is there a way to ban it or filter it automatically? Actually I'm processing it manually.

Comment: How do you get the message `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal` , do you run a command or *cat* some file? Because I think about monitoring the incoming requests and if the message `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal` is present than parse it to get the IP and block it.

Comment: I'm supposing someone tries to log in through ssh using a fake certificate, and that's how this message is being added to the auth.log

Comment: It would be interesting if some command/app  could monitor the ssh logs and trigger some script/action when a *condition* is found.  I searched for something like this but did not found anything.

Comment: I don't know much about `ssh` so I'm not sure how can I get `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal`. But I can watch `ssh`  logs by using `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` or `sudo journalctl --system --follow -u ssh.service`. So I guess you can pipe the journal output and search for `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal` like this: `sudo journalctl --system --follow -u ssh.service | while read -r line; do [[ echo "$line" | grep ssh_dispatch_run_fatal ]] && ..... ; done`

Comment: If `[[ echo "$line" | grep ssh_dispatch_run_fatal ]]` is true then you should parse the line to get only this section `XX.XXX.XXX.XX` and proceed to block it